# Let $G$ be connected graph and natural number $k$ that $rad(G) \leq k \leq diam(G)$. Prove there exists a vertex x, whose eccentricity equals $k$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Basically, I want to show that it is always possible to find a point in the graph G whose eccentricity (I denote the eccentricity of vertex x as ecc(x)) is equal to the given number k which satisfies the given inequality $rad(G) \leq k \leq diam(G)$. And I want to show it in such a way that I have a sequence of vertices $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$, where the eccentricity of the vertex $v_1$ is equal to the radius of the graph and the eccentricity of the vertex $v_n$ is equal to the diameter of the graph, and I create n-1 sets of the form {$ecc(v_i), ecc(v_j)$}, where $i=1,2,...n-1$ and $j=i+1$ so for any pair of these sets it is true that their intersection is always at least one eccentricity of vertex and I want to show that the union of these sets is interval, where every natural/integer value of eccentricity from closed interval $[rad(G), diam(G)]$ is present (so for any given value of $k$ there exists a vertex with eccentricity of $k$). Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does “set of the form $\text{ecc}(v_i)$” mean? What does “their intersection is one eccentricity of vertex” mean?

Comment: Oh, my fault, I edited the text, I meant the sets with two elements {$ecc(v_i), ecc(v_j)$} as you can see.

Comment: Or what were you asking? Are you giving me some hint?

Comment: "so for any pair of these sets it is true that their intersection is always at least one eccentricity of vertex and I want to show that the union of these sets is interval" Can you clarify this sentence?

Comment: Can you prove that if two vertices are adjacent their eccentricities differ by at  most $1$? Now what if you follow a path from a vertex of minimum eccentricity to a vertex of maximum eccentricity? Won't the vertices on the path take on all intermediate eccentricities?

Comment: Well actually yes, but what if we don't have this information (that eccentricities of adjacent vertices differ at most by 1), so then I would need to prove the original statement in a way that I need to show that every value of eccentricity (from the interval [radius, diameter] is present in a graph, like for some nonnegative integer numbers a,b,c,d, where $a \leq c \leq b$ and $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$, and I want to show that the union of these two closed intervals [a,b] and [c,d], where c is in [a,b], contains every integer between a and b (if $d \leq b$) or between a and d (if $b \leq d$).